# Correlation function in the critical two-dimensional Ising model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, correlation-functions, ising-model, critical-phenomena

Fifty years ago, McCoy and Wu in their book [*The Two-Dimensional Ising Model*](https://www.hup.harvard.edu/catalog.php?isbn=9780674180758) formulated a hypothesis about the correlation function in the critical two-dimensional Ising model. According to this hypothesis, when the model is exactly at the critical temperature, in the case when the distance between the two spins is large, the main term of the asymptotics of the correlation function has the form
$$
\langle \sigma_{0,0} \sigma_{M,N} \rangle \sim \frac{f(\vartheta)}{R^{1/4}}.
$$
Here $R = \sqrt{M^2 + N^2}$ is the distance between the spins, $\vartheta$ is the polar angle, and $f(\vartheta)$ is some function unknown in the general anisotropic case. For the isotropic case, McCoy and Wu additionally proposed the hypothesis that the function $f$ does not depend on the angle $\vartheta$. Both hypotheses are based on the results of McCoy and Wu for two special cases when $M = N$ or $M = 0$. In the second edition of the book, published in 2014, I do not see a new discussion of these hypotheses. I think that the second hypothesis looks plausible based on the widespread idea of the symmetries of the isotropic Ising model at the critical point. However, is it true that the function $f(\vartheta)$ is still not known for the anisotropic case?

Comment: I think this paper, published a few years after the first edition of the book, contains the results you are looking for:  https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.13.316
In the isotropic case, the correlation function only depends on $M^2 + N^2$, and in the anisotropic case, its dependence on N and M is given by the scaled variable $t$ in Eq. (2.5).

Comment: @SethWhitsitt I think you are right. Thanks.